# Weak form of 1D linear elliptical PDE, integration by parts

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finite-element-method

Please refer to the attached image.
I am struggling to understand how the integration by parts is performed for the weak form.
Can anyone please assist with an explanation?

The equation is not written as a PDE since it is in 1D

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how $\sigma$ and $u$ are related, the image is not really clear. It seems that $\sigma=Eu_x$ but what's $E$?

Comment: E is Youngs Modulus